# using setText() of TextView inside a Spinner's OnItemSelectedListener() method to set text ever time an item is selected. I keep getting errors

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    //Spinner used for Main menu of the App Where user selects their choice
    Spinner gSpinner,cSpinner,vSpinner;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
        gSpinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        cSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        vSpinner   = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");
        list.add("9");
        list.add("10");

        // Three SPINNERS created here*****************
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        spinnerArrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        gSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter1);
        gSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        spinnerArrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);
        cSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        spinnerArrayAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter3);
        vSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener2);

        //Get the application's resources
        resources = getResources();

        try
        {
            //Load the file from the raw folder - don't forget to OMIT the extension
            output = LoadFile("esv", true);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Display an error toast message
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "File: not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }



    }

    //LOAD FILES FROM THE APP "res/raw" FOLDER OR "assets" FOLDER
    public InputStream LoadFile(String fileName, boolean loadFromRawFolder) throws IOException
    {
        //Create a InputStream to read the file into
        InputStream iS;

        if (loadFromRawFolder)
        {
            //get the resource id from the file name
            int rID = resources.getIdentifier("com.example.john.semabible:raw/"+fileName, null, null);
            //get the file as a stream
            iS = resources.openRawResource(rID);
        }
        else
        {
            //get the file as a stream
            iS = resources.getAssets().open(fileName);
        }

        return iS;
    }



// the spinner's listener implementation - one for each spinner
// each implementation has a textview setText() that should update the text view // evrtime there is a change in the selection
    OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener =
            new OnItemSelectedListener(){



                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {

                    operateXml(output);

                    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);

                    // inflate (create) another copy of our custom layout
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, mainLayout, false);

                    // make changes to our custom layout and its subviews

                    TextView textView = (TextView)  myLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv);
                    textView.setText(vnText);  //gives error

                    // add our custom layout to the main layout
                    mainLayout.addView(myLayout);


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
            };


    OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
            new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {


                    operateXml(output);
                    LinearLayout mainLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);

                    // inflate (create) another copy of our custom layout
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, mainLayout1, false);

                    // make changes to our custom layout and its subviews

                    TextView textView = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv);
                    textView.setText(vnText); //gives errors

                    // add our custom layout to the main layout
                    mainLayout1.addView(myLayout);

                    chapter = Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());


            }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
};


    OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener2 =
            new OnItemSelectedListener(){


                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {

                    operateXml(output);

                    LinearLayout mainLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);

                    // inflate (create) another copy of our custom layout
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, mainLayout2, false);

                    // make changes to our custom layout and its subviews

                    TextView textView = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv);
                    textView.setText(vnText); //gives error

                    // add our custom layout to the main layout
                    mainLayout2.addView(myLayout);

                    verse = Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());


            }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
};
```

Comment: what errors? post them too!

Comment: post also your layouts `xml` files

Comment: where is vnText initialized?

Comment: Can you suggest me how to go about setting the textview from inside the onitemselectedlistener() method. should i declare the textview in main activity and reference it from within onitemselectedlistener() and if so how. Because i tried everything i could thinkk of but im missing some crucial understanding of how this works so need our help. what i want is simple as the question itself. show me a working exmple if ou can. im new to this site and lots of formatting issues being faced.

Comment: vnText is a Global String Variable that is initialised after parsing an xml file 
from a method i didn't mention here.  Using textview setext() from within onCreate() doesnt give me any issues. But when used within the Listener method it gives a NullPointerException error.

Comment: You get the `NullPointerException` most probably because your `textView` is null. That's why I asked you to post your `xml` files and the complete error log

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
textView.setText(vnText);
```

Write this code :

```
textView.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

Instead of this:

```
OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener =
            new OnItemSelectedListener()
```

Write this:

```
OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener =
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
```

Also instead of this:

```
  @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id)
```

Pass respective adapter of each spinner instead of parent:
e.g for spinner one it should be like:

```
  @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinnerArrayAdapter1, View view,
                                           int position, long id)
```

Comment: This will work . Give it a try and do let me know. Also dont forget to mark my post as answer to your question if my solution works. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Do you want to put the selected value to your textview? If yes then this is your answer.

Comment: I edited my answer please implement these changes and then update your textView. This will work if you need further assistance after implementing these changes do let me know.

Comment: for more help also share your error log It will help me to reach to exact point of problem